# Adding classes/ids to forms in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to add classes and ids to specific elements of a form in Laravel 4.  For example, I would like this:

```
<textarea type="text" id="description" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#f0f7f8');" onblur="setbg('white')" name="description" value="" rows="10"></textarea>
```

to be applied to:

```
{{ Form::label('description', 'Description:') }}
{{ Form::textarea('description')}}
```

I didn't see this in the documentation.  Thank you!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the third parameter for the `Form::textarea` method, passing a key-value array. Ex:

```
Form::textarea('description', null, [
    'id'      => 'description',
    'rows'    => 10,
]);
```

Comment: However, when I do this, something happens with the focus.  The output:  

<textarea id="description" onfocus="this.value=&#039;&#039;; setbg(&#039;$f0f7f8&#039;);" onblur="setbg(&#039;white&#039;)" rows="10" name="description" cols="50"></textarea>

Comment: The textbox isn't appearing in the color that I want when resting.

Comment: Oh, it seems to be escaping the value. On that case, it's gonna be quite a pain in the ass to solve, since we'll have to create new class, extending `HtmlBuilder`, overwrite the `attributeElement` method and make it not call the `e` method, which is what effectively escapes the content, and finally register this new class of ours as the `html` component of the app. Apart from being such a pain in the ass, it's bad because it disables escaping for all your HTML functionality... To be honest, you should really setup your events through JavaScript, at the end of the page...

Answer (score 0):

Although its an old question, I just wanted to say that you can escape the javascript like this:

```
Form::textarea('description', null, array(
    'id'      => 'description',
    'rows'    => 10,
    'onFocus' => 'this.value=\'\'; setbg(\'#f0f7f8\');'
));
```

Thats it :)